# Forward declaration of class in different namespaces

Tags: c++, c++17

I already searched for questions about forward declaration but couldn't find a answer to my case.

I have a class Foo:

**Foo.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace aaa::xxx::yyy::zzz
{
    class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() = default;

        std::string get_value() const
        {
            return m_value;
        }

        void set_value(const std::string& value)
        {
            m_value = value;
        }
    private:
        std::string m_value{};
    };
}
```

This `class Foo` is used in annother `class Bar`:

**Bar.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace aaa::xxx::yyy::zzz 
{
    class Foo;
}

namespace aaa::bbb::ccc::ddd
{
    using Foo = aaa::xxx::yyy::zzz::Foo;

    class Bar 
    {
    public:
        Bar() = default;

        Foo get_foo() const;
    private:
        Foo m_foo{};
    };

}
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
#include "Bar.h"

#include "Foo.h"

namespace aaa::bbb::ccc::ddd
{
    using Foo = aaa::xxx::yyy::zzz::Foo;

    Foo Bar::get_foo() const
    {
        return m_foo;
    }

}
```

Now i dont know what i did wrong with the forwad declaration. I declared class Foo before `class Bar` with its namespace but still its states that `class Foo` is undefined.

So the Question is how to forward class Foo correctly?

EDIT:
Changing `Foo m_foo{};` to `Foo m_foo;` as suggested still produces the same error.

Comment: `Foo m_foo{};` requires `Foo` to be fully defined. You can't use a forward declaration here

Comment: @UnholySheep good catch. The missing error would have stated this.

Comment: Even if i change it to `Foo m_foo` it still states the same error. is it because it has no constructor except the default one?